# ActionFilterAttribute - Event Order

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On a controller method annotated [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which happens first, the OnActionExecuting or the OnResulting methods?

What is the order that things happen? I've read the MSDN page but it isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's all on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx

1. **OnAuthorization** - run before anything, to make security decisions
2. **OnActionExecuting** – called when a controller action is executed
3. **OnActionExecuted** – called after a controller action is executed
4. **OnResultExecuting** – called before a controller action result is executed
5. **OnResultExecuted** – called after a controller action result is executed

Exception filters (OnException) run when errors occur

Comment: NB. OnAuthorization is only fires when using AuthorizationFilterAttribute

Answer (score 2):

It should be the following order:

1. OnActionExecuting
2. OnActionExecuted
3. OnResultExcuting
4. OnResultExecuted